# How to know what plot was clicked in Jfreechart java?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Hellow everyone. I hope you can help me. I'm using jfreechart and java to display charts. I have used a CombinedDomainXYPlot and I added 3 XYPlots as subplots. Well, I need to add anotations to every subplot and I would like to do it when I click on XYPlot, but I have to know what XYPlot was clicked. how can I do it?

Comment: I've got it. PlotEntity plot = (PlotEntity) cme.getEntity(); XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot)(plot.getPlot()); but i can't get the value X or value Y clicked. Does Anyone know?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the new code or your [mcve]? It'll be more readable than a comment. The `Plot` and most kinds of `ChartEntity` have a `getDataset()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach event listner on your jfreeChart. Refer link for the listener -

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/package-summary.html